# Passing parameters variable to a JQuery function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem about putting variables into a date,

```
var tgl_jam = $(".looping .content .form_prediksi #tgl_jam").val();     

$(".count_down").countdown({

        var tgl_jam = $(".looping .content .form_prediksi #tgl_jam").val(); 
        date: ""+ tgl_jam ,
        //tgl_jam,
        //date: "", // Change this to your desired date to countdown to  date: "2014-03-15 00:00:00",
        format: "off"


    });
```

Comment: what is the value of `tgl_jam`?

Answer (score 0):

Put the following block outside of the `countdown` call:

```
var tgl_jam = $(".looping .content .form_prediksi #tgl_jam").val();
```

The code shall be:

```
var tgl_jam = $(".looping .content .form_prediksi #tgl_jam").val();
$(".count_down").countdown({
    date: ""+ tgl_jam,
```

of course, this assumes that your `tgl_jam` would be in the format `2014-03-15 00:00:00`

Comment: thaks, but [+tgl_jam] not get parameter from the variable